# how to disable past day on table calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, table-calendar

i use package table calendar, how to disable table calendar past day on flutter
if on week view hide all past day
on mont view grey all past day on this month and disable to past month

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBUYW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
showDatePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                                    lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
),
```